# How to define the weak formulation of a convection-diffusion problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to define the weak formulation of the following convection-diffusion problem:

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
u_x+z u_y=D(x,y) u_{z z} \; \; \text{in} \; \; \Omega := [0,L] \times [-y_0,y_0] \times [-z_0, z_0] \;\; \text{where} \;L,y_0,z_0 \; \epsilon \;R^+ \\
u_z(x,y,\pm z_0)=0 \; \; \text{for} \;\;(x,y) \;\epsilon \;[0,L] \times [-y_0,y_0]\\
u(0,y,z) = f(y,z) \; \; \text{for} \; \; (y,z) \; \epsilon \; [-y_0,y_0] \times [-z_0,z_0] \\
u(x,y,z) =0 \; \; \text{when} \begin{cases}
y=-y_0 \; \; \text{and} \; \; z>0\\
or\\
y=y_0 \; \; \text{and} \; \; z<0
\end{cases}   
\label{Eq-1}
\end{split}
\end{align}
where $D(x,y)$ is a positive, decreasing function.

After multiplying the PDE with a test function $v$, integrating over $\Omega$ and using integration by parts to the RHS we arrive at the weak formulation, that is:

*Find the weak solution* $u \; \epsilon \; H^1(\Omega)$ *that satisfies*:

\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega u_x v d\Omega+\int_\Omega zu_yv d\Omega=-\int_\Omega D u_z v_z d\Omega   
\end{equation}

**I wonder now how to define the space of the test function** $v$.